# Main differences between software design processes

Tags: software-design, waterfall, rational-unified-process

I want to compare the following software design processes.

- [Waterfall model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model)
- [V-Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-Model_%28software_development%29)
- [Unified Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Process)

The `V-Model` has test phases for each specification phase, the `waterfall model` doesn't.
The `Unified Process` is iterative and incremental, the others aren't.

Are those the main differences? Is there something to add?
I only need the main differences, not too detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The water fall model is not iterative.
2. V-Model is iterative in the sense that

   a. It uses unit testing to verify procedural design

   b. It uses integration testing to verify architectural (system) design

   c. It uses acceptance testing to validate the requirements

   d. If problems are found during verification and validation, the left side of the V can be  re-executed before testing on the right side is re-enacted
3. Unified Process Model is iterative

   a. System delivered in pieces.

   b. Allows production system and development system to run in parallel.

   c. Reduces risk and uncertainty in the development